# javaFX width css not reacting?

Tags: css, javafx, width, fxml, scrollpane

Im trying to get a dynamic scrollpane in my JavaFX (FXML) application using CSS. my CSS for the scrollpane looks like this:

```
.scroll-pane {
     -fx-width: 80%;
     -fx-height: 80%;
     -fx-background-color: #FF3333;
}
```

the color works, but the size properties don't if I open the CSS in JavaFX scene builder it doesn't show the height and width lines at all.

I assume im missing something pretty basic, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know you cant use `-fx-width/-fx-height` at all and you cant use percentage values for it. The width and height of elements are read-only. You can set `-fx-pref-width`, `-fx-pref-height`, `-fx-max-width`, `-fx-min-width`, `-fx-max-height` and `-fx-min-height` to adjust the size of Java FX elements.

Check the [CSS Reference Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) out to see which CSS styles are possible.

If you want to have the size as percentage you probably need to bind the size to another property.

As example:

```
myView.prefWidthProperty().bind(myOtherView.widthProperty().multiply(0.75));
```

There is another post about percentage values with the use of a GridLayout.
[How do specify a width percentage in JavaFX 2 using FXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832896/how-do-specify-a-width-percentage-in-javafx-2-using-fxml)